# What is the Biblical basis against Melchizedek being the Holy Spirit?

Tags: exegesis, biblical-basis, pneumatology, hebrews, melchizedek

A friend of mine is part of a church that teaches that Hebrews 7 indicates that Melchizedek is the Holy Spirit. What are the arguments against this view?

For reference, here is [Hebrews 7:15–21 (NIV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+7:15-21&version=NIV):

> **Jesus Like Melchizedek**
>
> 15 And what we have said is even more clear if another priest like
>   Melchizedek appears,
>   16 one who has become a priest not on the basis
>   of a regulation as to his ancestry but on the basis of the power of an
>   indestructible life.
>   17 For it is declared:
>
> > “You are a priest forever,
> >         in the order of Melchizedek.”
>
> 18 The former regulation is set aside because it was weak and useless
>   19 (for the law made nothing
>   perfect), and a better hope is introduced, by which we draw near to
>   God.
>
> 20 And it was not without an oath! Others became priests without any
>   oath, 21 but he became a priest with an oath when God said to him:
>
> > “The Lord has sworn
> >         and will not change his mind:
> >         ‘You are a priest forever.’”

It's also written in [Hebrew 7:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+7:3&version=KJV) (KJV),

> Without father, without mother, without descent, having neither beginning of days, nor end of life; but made like unto the Son of God; abideth a priest continually.

I am a bit confused here. Anbody?

Comment: I don't see how that passage even remotely suggests Melchizedek is the holy spirit. Please explain in more detail...

Comment: Absent any real indication of why one might think Mechizedek is the Holy Spirit, I don't see why one would expect a biblical statement to the contrary.  The Bible is too short to contain explicit statements "X is not Y" for every two randomly chosen persons X and Y.  I might as well ask "Is there a biblical basis against Noah being the apostle Philip?" Probably not, but why should there be?

Comment: It might help if you identified the church that your friend belongs to, and quoted and/or linked to a statement from that church about its belief that Melchizedek is the Holy Spirit. Then answers could be more specific and directed at the particular belief whose (biblically based) refutation you are asking for.

Comment: I cannot do that. Sorry.

Comment: @curiousdannii .   ..... It says without mother....without descent!  I doubt that it is the Father himself, and we know that Jesus was born of the Father first before he created the world, and also born of Mary.   I think it can only be the Holy Spirit.   You can see my reply below to dick Harfield.

Answer (score 3):

The Book of Hebrews speaks of Melchisedec 9 times (5:6,10; 6:20; 7:1,10,11,15,17,21) and in each case it is to inform us that Jesus is made a priest in the order of Melchisedec. The theology of *Hebrews* is strange, but no more so than in its portrayal of Jesus as a priest in the order of Melchisedec. The [filioque](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=filioque) clause that now forms part of the Nicene Creed, states that the Holy Spirit comes from the Father *and from the Son* [Jesus]. I think this clause requires some serious mental gymnastics to read from *Hebrews* that Melchisedec is the Holy Spirit.

Melchisedec is first mentioned in Genesis 14:18, where he is the King of Salem and priest of the most high God. Again, it is not traditional to think of the Holy Spirit, the third person of the Trinity, as merely a priest of God. Melchisedec can not be the Holy Spirit.

Hebrews 7:3 speaks of Melchisedec in terms that could at first read like divinity: *without father, without mother, without descent, having neither beginning of days, nor end of life; but made like unto the Son of God*.  The NAB footnote to this passge explains:

> 4 ... this is perhaps a quotation from a hymn about Melchizedek. The rabbis maintained that anything not mentioned in the Torah does not exist. Consequently, since the Old Testament nowhere mentions Melchizedek's ancestry, birth, or death, the conclusion can be drawn that he remains . . . forever.